# Is there a blockchain explorer that allows me to see a contract's data?

Tags: contract-debugging, explorers

I've looked at the three blockchain explorers available, but AFAICT none of them provide the ability to look at the contract's data.  They only allow you to see the code.

How can I examine a contract's data for a historical transaction?

Comment: What's ether.camp missing?  Example: https://live.ether.camp/account/4eecf99d543b278106ac0c0e8ffe616f2137f10a

Comment: ether.camp is missing making it obvious :-).  I thought I'd looked for that but I missed it.

so is ether.camp the only one that allow you to see contract storage?

Comment: you answered the question btw. Please give a detailed response about who supports what in a stackexchange answer.  Or I'll do that if you want.

Comment: okay, I edited.  Please mark as duplicate, and check my edits.